# How to go to a specific frame on click event

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have created a flash with five movie clips. I want when I press each of them to go and play specific frames on the main timeline? How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
btn.addEventListener(
    MouseEvent.CLICK,
    function(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        MovieClip(root).gotoAndPlay(18);
    }
);
```

Where `btn` is the button instance name, and `18` is the frame you want the main timeline to play from.

Or you can write a function to make it easy to assign to multiple buttons:

```
function clickFrame(button:Sprite, frame:int):void
{
    button.addEventListener(
        MouseEvent.CLICK,
        function(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            MovieClip(root).gotoAndPlay(frame);
        }
    );
}

clickFrame(btn1, 18);
clickFrame(btn2, 67);
clickFrame(btn3, 114);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it keeps looping to the next frame as soon as the button is clicked try adding

```
>>stop();
btn.addEventListener(
    MouseEvent.CLICK,
    function(e:MouseEvent):void {
        MovieClip(root).gotoAndPlay(18);
        ***stop();***
 });
```